# How to plot a line with temperature and datetime, retrieved with MySQL, in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

We have set up a MySQL database, where we have stored temperature data. We now want to retrieve this data, and then plot it. What we have done is following:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://xxx:xxx@xxx@localhost/xxx")
conn = engine.connect()

list_temp = []
list_time = []

list_temp = pd.read_sql('SELECT temperature FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic="lpn1"', conn).astype(float).values
list_time = pd.read_sql('SELECT timestamp FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic="lpn1"', conn).astype(str).values
```

Where above is to establish connection to the MySQL database, and then we retrieve data and timestamp from the database. If we print list_temp and list_time we see this:

```
[[30.4 ]
 [29.71]
 [29.46]
 ...
 [20.07]
 [21.05]
 [21.87]]
[['2019-07-26 15:09:25']
 ['2019-07-26 15:24:26']
 ['2019-07-26 15:39:26']
 ...
 ['2019-08-20 14:07:49']
 ['2019-08-20 14:22:49']
 ['2019-08-20 14:37:49']]
```

Which indicates that they are nested...

We then try to save a plot by doing this:

```
# plot
plt.plot(list_time,list_temp)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

Unfortunately, we receive this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` and of course we suspect that this must be because our values are nested.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list_temp is a list with one element, which is the list with your data. The same thing with list_time. So replace this line

```
plt.plot(list_time,list_temp)
```

with this:

```
plt.plot(list_time[:,0], list_temp[:,0])
```

to take the inner list.

Comment: Have tried, but only receiving 1 value from each. print: [30.4]
['2019-07-26 15:09:25']

Comment: @YusufSahebzadeh sorry, there was a little bug, now it should work